# What's the proper way of defining or documenting calls handled by __getattr__?

Tags: python, autocomplete, documentation, getattr

I have a class who's job is to wrap another class (code I don't control), intercept all calls to the wrapped class, perform some logic, and pass along the call to the underlying class. Here's an example:

```python
class GithubRepository(object):

    def get_commit(self, sha):
        return 'Commit {}'.format(sha)

    def get_contributors(self):
        return ['bobbytables']


class LoggingGithubRepositoryWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, github_repository):
        self._github_repository = github_repository

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        base_func = getattr(self._github_repository, name)

        def log_wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print "Calling {}".format(name)
            return base_func(*args, **kwargs)

        return log_wrap

if __name__ == '__main__':

    git_client = LoggingGithubRepositoryWrapper(GithubRepository())

    print git_client.get_commit('abcdef1245')
    print git_client.get_contributors()
```

As you can see, the way that I do this is by implementing `__getattr__` on the wrapping class and delegating to the underlying class. The downside to this approach is that users of `LoggingGithubRepositoryWrapper` don't know which attributes/methods the underlying `GithubRepository` actually has.

This leads me to my question: **is there a way to define or document the calls handled by `__getattr__`?** Ideally, I'd like to be able to autocomplete on `git_client.` and be provided a list of supported methods. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: No, there isn't - Python is highly dynamic, so once you put `__getattr__` in the mix it's more-or-less impossible to tell what could work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few different ways, but they wont involve the use of `__getattr__`.

What you really need to do is dynamically create your class, or at least dynamically create the wrapped functions on your class.  There are a few ways to do this in python.

You could build the class definition using `type()` or metaclasses, or build it on class instantiation using the `__new__` method.

Every time you call `LoggingGithubRepositoryWrapper()`, the `__new__` method will be called.  Here, it looks at all the attributes on the `github_repository` argument and finds all the non-private methods.  It then creates a function on the instantiated `LoggingGithubRepositoryWrapper` class instance that wraps the repo call in a logging statement.

At the end, it passes back the modified class instance.  Then `__init__` is called.

```
from types import MethodType


class LoggingGithubRepositoryWrapper(object):

    def __new__(cls, github_repository):
        self = super(LoggingGithubRepositoryWrapper, cls).__new__(cls)
        for name in dir(github_repository):
            if name.startswith('__'):
                continue
            func = getattr(github_repository, name)            
            if isinstance(func, MethodType):                
                setattr(self, name, cls.log_wrap(func))
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def log_wrap(func):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print 'Calling {0}'.format(func.__name__)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap

    def __init__(self, github_repository):
        ... # this is all the same
```